# Embedded signing with Docusign with Jwt Oauth2 authorisation without customer login/consent

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, docusignapi

In my laravel application I have to integrate embedded signing with docusign with  jwt oauth2  without customer login/consent window. The application developer has one account in docusign, customers dont have any account. Customers has to do embedded signing with docusign(set by the application developer in docusign account) without asking any consent/login.

Which function I should use requestJWTApplicationToken/requestJWTUserToken from the phpSDK for this? What is the scope I have to use? Consent/login window should not appear.
How can we do this?

Comment: How can I get the access token without any consent from customer side.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the best answer to your questions! And upvote any useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that there are two different users involved in your use case.

User 1 is someone in your company with a login to the DocuSign system. For the signing scenario, this is often a "system user" such as "finance@your_company.com" -- not a real person.

User 2 is the signer. They usually do NOT have a login on DocuSign. And they do NOT need a login on DocuSign.

Here are the steps:

1. User 2, the signer, pushes a `Sign` button on your application.
2. Your application, in the back end server, uses the JWT User Token call as Ben recommends to create an access_token for User 1. (Save/cache the access token and only create a new one when needed.)
3. Your application, in the back end, uses the access token to create/send the DocuSign envelope, and to obtain the Signing Ceremony URL from DocuSign for the envelope.
4. Your application redirects the user's browser to the Signing Ceremony URL
5. After the signer (user 2) finishes signing, their browser is redirected back to your application.

Notes:

1. The Consent process is a one time step that is done by the User 1 or on their behalf via Administrative consent. [Details](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent).
2. If you don't want to redirect the user's browser away from your app and over to the Signing Ceremony, as an alternative you can open a new browser tab for the Signing Ceremony, and then programmatically close it when the signing is done.
3. During the steps shown above (JWT flow, creating an envelope, obtaining the Signing Ceremony URL), it is a good idea to provide a busy indicator to the user so they are reassured that something is happening.

### Added

Q from the OP:

> So our application has to run a script to create a jwt access token once for the docusign account user (user1) from our application backend and using that single access token with rest api, every customer (like user2) in the frontend can sign the docusign. We have to keep the backend script in cron so that before token expires, we will get new a access token for the user1 and this new token used for the further rest api call. Right?

A: Correct, except for the cron job. Since JWT access tokens last an hour, a cron job is not appropriate. Instead, implement a backend `check_token` method that does something like (pseudo-code):

```
function check_token
# Returns a DocuSign access token or raises an error
   $access_token = get_access_token_from_cache(); # May return null
   $access_token_expires = get_access_token_expires_from_cache()
   $current_datetime = get_current_time();

   if ($access_token == null || 
      $access_token_expires < $current_datetime) 
      then begin
         # need a new access token
         ($access_token, $expires_in) = jwt_get_access_token()
         # Note that the $expires_in is in seconds.

         # Use the $expires_in to calculate an $access_token_expires
         # datetime. Use a 10 minute buffer period to not try using
         # the access_token when it gets close to expiring
         $current_datetime = get_current_time();
         # The following is not in PHP! It is pseudo code
         $access_token_expires = date_add_seconds($current_datetime,
            $expires_in - (10 * 60));
         store_access_token_in_cache($access_token);
         store_access_token_expires_in_cache($access_token_expires);
      end
   return ($access_token)
end function
```

### Note

The access_token and access_token_expires values are cached for your application as a whole, not per session. If your app has a database you can store the values there. Or use a file on the server. Or a sharedMemory cache if you're on Linux. Etc.

Comment: Thanks Larry for the detailed explanation. So our application has to run a script to create a jwt access token once for the docusign account user (user1) from our application backend  and using that single access token with rest api , every customers(like user2) in the frontend can sign the docusign . We have to keep the backend script in cron so that before token expires, we will get new a access token for the user1 and this new  token used for the further rest api call. right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use requestJWTUserToken and the scopes are signature and impersonation. The user is the one doing the consent with JWT auth not your customer. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) here. [Also have a look at our code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php) in PHP for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

### Approve your application

In Apps and Keys in your Docusign developer portal :

1. Create App and integration key
2. Generate RSA key pair - keep them
3. Add redirect URI http://localhost
4. Open this link to approve your app (change client-id/integration key) => https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?scope=signature%20permission_read%20user_read%20account_read%20domain_read%20impersonation&redirect_uri=http://localhost&client_id=your-client-id&response_type=code
5. Allow access and ignore the redirection

### Get an access token in your Laravel app

1. Install the library https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client
2. Save your private key (the one generated in Apps and Keys) in the storage folder as docusign-private-dev.key
3. Implement the code (fit it to your needs)

> ```
> $host = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';
> $clientId = 'your-client-id'; // integration key
> $userId = 'your-user-id'; // the one in Apps and Keys
> $scopes = 'signature permission_read user_read account_read domain_read impersonation';
>
> $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
> $config->setHost($host);
>
> $oAuth = new \DocuSign\eSign\Client\Auth\OAuth();
> $oAuth->setBasePath($host)->setOAuthBasePath();
>
> $apiClient = new \DocuSign\eSign\client\ApiClient($config, $oAuth);
>
> $privateKey = file_get_contents(storage_path('docusign-private-dev.key'));
>
> $jwt = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken($clientId, $userId, $privateKey, $scopes);
>
> $accessToken = $jwt[0]['access_token'];
>
> // Get user info with token
> $userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
> ```

With `requestJWTUserToken` the token is automatically attached to your next API calls.